# Почему общий второстепенный член не повлиял на запятую?

Tags: егэ

> На далёком западном крае неба (1) исступленно метались белые молнии (2)
> и (3) хотя гроза не собиралась двигаться в нашу сторону (4) всё же
> что-то тревожное было в этом таинственном ожидании природы

Почему "на далеком западном крае неба" не будет общим второстепенным членом для грамматических основ "молнии метались" и "было что-то тревожное"? Взято из сборника Цыбулько, ответ 234, а мне кажется, что правильнее было бы 34

Answer (score 1):

Правильно:

*(1) **На далёком западном крае неба** исступленно метались белые молнии, и, (2) хотя гроза не собиралась двигаться в нашу сторону,  (3) всё же что-то тревожное было в этом таинственном ожидании природы.*

1. Это сложное предложение с сочинительной и подчинительной связью, состоящее их трех простых предложений. Предложения (2) и (3) составляют сложноподчиненное предложение (СПП), союз И соединяет предложение (1) и СПП.

Обстоятельство «на далёком западном крае неба» **относится только к предложению (1)** и поэтому не является общим элементом.

2. Это правило (об общем элементе)  **не надо понимать формально** – оно имеет вполне определенный смысл. Если мы не ставим запятую перед союзом И, то это означает, что два предложения связаны между собой и читаются без обозначения паузы в одну фразу, при этом обстоятельство является общим для них (как бы связывает их).

Такое возможно, если предложения семантически **однородны,** то есть независимы между собой (при отсутствии союза их даже можно прочитать с перечислительной интонацией), но раскрывают **одну общую тему** – в данном случае то, что происходит на небе.

3. Но ведь в предложении это не так: два последующих предложения  **не имеют отношения** «к небу», это уже тема другого сообщения.

Поэтому обстоятельство не является общим второстепенным членом, запятая перед союзом И ставится.